# Generic type for OO classes in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to have a generic type that can represent any class in a simple class diagram. In this case a class contains:

1. A name
2. Any number of arguments of any type
3. Any number of functions that takes any number of arguments of any type

I have only used simple ADT declarations which is not working in this case, for example this is what I have been stuck with but it gives me no where near the type of flexibility I'm after:

```
data Attr a = Attr { name :: String
                   , kind :: a}
              deriving (Show)

data Action = Action { name1 :: String
                     , params :: [Attr Int]}
              deriving (Show)

data Class a = NewC { name2 :: String
                    , attrs :: [Attr Int]
                    , actions :: [Action]}
            deriving (Show)
```

So my question is now how would I go about representing any arbitrary class in Haskell?

I do not want to do OOP in haskell. Imaging that the class type I'm trying to make will be a node in a graph. However each node in the graph will be a different class.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is your use case? This seems like an [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Do you want to do OOP with classes in Haskell, or do you want to represent in Haskell classes from some other language?

Comment: No I do not want to do OOP in haskell. Imaging that the class type I'm trying to make will be a node in a graph.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with this type. Do you want to represent just the syntax of another language, which happens to be OO? Or are you trying to write an interpreter for such language, and you need to represent objects (not just classes) in that language?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to represent your class diagrams entirely as values rather than a mix of values and types. Instead of `Attr Int`, for example, you might use something like `Attr { name="Int", kind=PrimitiveInt }`. I've introduced an `OopType` type below.

```
data Attr   = Attr { name :: String
                   , kind :: OopType}
              deriving (Show)

data Action = Action { name1 :: String
                     , params :: [Attr]}
              deriving (Show)

data Class   = NewC { name2 :: String
                    , attrs :: [Attr]
                    , actions :: [Action]}
            deriving (Show)

data OopType = ClassType Class
             | InterfaceType Class   -- TODO make a dedicated interface type
             | Enum                  -- TODO make a dedicated enum type
             | PrimitiveString
             | PrimitiveInt
```

Note that this representation doesn't model 'generics' (that is, classes that are parameterised by types). To do that, you'd add another field to the Class type.